# embedded variable in R string

Tags: r

I am trying to loop and rename colnames in a data frame.

How can I embed a numeric variable in the R's colname string. I found the .(x) associated to the bquote/paste method for title in graphics but it doesn't work with a standard string.

In Ruby I can embed a variable in a string using #{x} in the following way

```
irb(main):005:0> (1..10).each{|i| p "hello no #{i}"}
"hello no 1"
"hello no 2"
"hello no 3"
"hello no 4"
"hello no 5"
"hello no 6"
"hello no 7"
"hello no 8"
"hello no 9"
"hello no 10"
```

Thanks

Comment: `paste`? There is also `sprintf` but that's probably overkill.

Comment: Thanks, actually paste() works fine.I just messed up with .(x) instead of using a paste(name,num)

Comment: Both `paste` and `sprintf` are vectorized, so you might not even need the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `sprintf()`. For example:

```
i <- 4;
data[[sprintf("hello.%1.2d",i)]] <- ...;
```